# How to improve GNOME 3 performance?

Tags: gnome, performance

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, and I have been increasingly noticing poor performance. Even as I type out this question, there are periods of a second or two where input essentially freezes. There's constantly at least a 1-second delay to every click I make, and in general I am noticing poor FPS for animations and such.

My computer is no slouch either, I am running an Intel i7 10700KF and a GTX 970, so the fact that I can't even perform basic desktop tasks without latency is honestly frustrating.

Are there any changes I can make to improve GNOME performance? Does anyone else experience such lag / poor performance?

Comment: Please look at system log for any errors. E.g., `tail -f /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Consider using MATE, KDE, XFCE or LXQt. All of them perform much better than GNOME, in any hardware.

Comment: How much RAM and swap do you have? Do `free;uptime` and [edit] your Question. Do not use Add comment to reply.

Comment: Is the system installed to an internal SSD or HDD? Is the `/home` partition on a different drive? Is your display plugged into the GPU?  When did this problem start and what kinds of things were you doing on your device in the days leading up to the problem's onset (like adding/removing software of making changes to system files or configs)